Stochastic blockmodel with continuous weights in [0,1]
I want to use a stochastic blockmodel (SBM) to cluster the nodes in a network where the edge weights are continuous numbers between 0 and 1. It seems that R-packages such as blockmodels and SBM offer Bernoulli, Poisson, and Gaussian distributions for the weights. Gaussian is the only continuous distribution on offer (in the packages I have looked at), but my weights are distributed so that the mode is at 0 (minimum value) with some weights exactly zero (probably not a problem as non-existing edges seem to be allowed) and the other ones strongly skewly distributed from the mode at zero upwards. I do understand that the Gaussian model in the SBM does not necessarily imply that the weights have to be Gaussian distributed overall as it can be a mixture of different Gaussians for within and between communities, but still there seems to be no way to put together a mixture of two or a few Gaussians to emulate the weights distribution that I have. Furthermore I am surprised to have a Gaussian distribution assumed for edge weights in the first place as in pretty much all situations I know of the weights are constrained to be positive, and the Gaussian distribution puts mass on the whole real line (of course it is occasionally still a good approximation for positive data). For the kind of weights distribution I have, any fitted Gaussian would put considerable probability mass on the negative side.
What to do in such a case? Fit a Gaussian model regardless? Are there any versions of the SBM implemented that assume other distributions such as exponential or Beta? Should I transform the weights to "near Gaussian" if possible?
More generally, do I understand correctly that the Gaussian assumption applies to the raw weights (separately between and within communities) rather than some latent variable or something that would allow for strongly non-Gaussian weights? I find it surprisingly difficult to find a comprehensive explanation of the SBM for continuous weights. Also it seems strange to me that the only model available for continuous data seems to be a model that as a standard generates negative values when in practice all I have seen is weights constrained to be non-negative.

You are right that the gaussian distribution refers to the numerical weights of the edges, and you are right that the marginal distribution of these edges is not where the gaussian is fitted, but rather the inter-community and within-commumity subgroups of edges, which means that, from an ideal theorical perspective, the marginal distribution should indeed be some mixture of normals.
However, in statistics it's very often unnecessary and even pointless to expect data where a normal is fitted, to actually distribute normally. The normal distribution is used first and foremost because its likelihood corresponds to least squares method. Basically, you'd use gaussian likelihood because you want to find the within-community mean weights, and compare them with the inter-community ones. Even if weights were binary (as in standard SBM) gaussian likelihood would find the proportions of 1s pretty well and converge on similar groups as the binary method, although not quite as well.

Are there any versions of the SBM implemented that assume other distributions such as exponential or Beta?

SBM inference is basically expectation-maximization (EM), which works perfecty with exponential likelihood, although it's just so much easier to find it implemented just for gaussian likelihood... For beta I'm not so sure, beta is trickier as it takes two parameters, maybe it would work using the method of moments, but I'd need to get studying this myself to give you a better answer.

Thanks, this helps!
